# Duplicate Profiles - DUDE_WITH_J

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, spamming

[DUDE_WITH_J - Profile 1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/144409/dude-with-j)

[DUDE_WITH_J - Profile 2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/144374/dude-with-j) (changed to just DUDE)

[DUDE_WITH_J - Profile 3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/144419/dude-with-j?tab=profile)

These two users have the same name, with different DPs and different rep values. Profile 1 is new here, while Profile 2 opened yesterday and has given 1 answer and 2 questions (1 with a net of 2 upvotes and another new one).

This raises concern that spammers might be here.

1. The person in the 1st profile asked a question " [how the oxidative cleavage formed here I am getting confused](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181338/picric-acid-is-formed-when-there-is-concentrated-hno3-and-h2so4-then-why-it-form) " which looks like HW and is likely to be closed as HW, with content issues as well (all small letters, no proper punctuation)
2. 2nd profile has asked 2 questions and answered 1, [1 question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181316/product-of-4-chlorobutan-1-ol-treated-with-koh-in-alcohol) got 2 upvotes while the [other](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181337/a-5mem-ring-compound-a-reacting-with-ch3oh-and-ch3o-to-form-compound-and) is new. The 1st one was initially asked with the same content issues, and it was edited by [Karsten](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/72973/karsten) (thank you for checking out my flag!)

I put out a so-called 'canned notice' like how Poutnik calls it, for formatting issues as below, and he responded with:

[image]

The [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/181328/139890) put out by him / her for [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157436/why-do-ketoses-undergo-dehydration-more-rapidly-than-aldoses) - fails an AI-detection test.

[image]
[image]

Can the community please advise?

Comment: Another user in concern: [Drew Mitchell](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/144397/drew-mitchell)

Comment: It is helpful to keep an eye out and report misuse of the site. Keep in mind that the best way to report what looks like misconduct is to raise a flag (it looks like you did this at least once) since it protects your privacy and ours, as well as that of the presumed perp, who might be a nice person despite being clueless about how the site works.

Comment: Please note that having multiple accounts is not [banned outright](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets/388985#388985).  However it is highly suspicious since the only reason to have multiple accounts would seem to be to avoid a ban or use as a sockpuppet to [upvote your q&as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301553/is-it-legal-on-se-network-for-a-person-to-have-two-accounts/301554#301554).

Comment: @BuckThorn both reasons don't look feasible for me. The user is *new* to the site, has asked a few questions (one with -4 score) and I don't think he / she is in a situation to be banned by Roomba. 'Sockpuppet to vote' also doesn't look fine as voting opens only at 25 rep.

Comment: Noobs often use guest accounts.